# What is better to use Equal or EqualError

Tags: go, testify

I don't see any difference to use in testing `EqualError` vs `Equal`. my question is What does `EqualError` extra?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/require#EqualError), `EqualError` takes `error` as its 2nd and third arguments, while `Equal` takes `any`.

When checking the value of an `error`, you should use `EqualError`. If not, use `Equal`.

Comment: @yakob-abada, to understand what the answer means, you might refresh yourself on what ["sentinel errors" are](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully). Basically, what check to use depends on what _aspect_ of your error you want to check: if it must be a sentinel error, use `EqualError`, otherwise you might want to check the error's message contains specific text, or assert some other facts about it.